# ERROR: Unexpected error Ambari repo file path not set for current OS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, data-science, ambari

i am trying to install apache ambari on linux mint. The installation completed sucessfully but when i try to setup the server i am getting some error. which is as following

```
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Setup ambari-server
Checking SELinux...
WARNING: Could not run /usr/sbin/sestatus: OK
Customize user account for ambari-server daemon [y/n] (n)? y
Enter user account for ambari-server daemon (root):root
ERROR: Unexpected error Ambari repo file path not set for current
OS.
ERROR: Exiting with exit code 1. 
REASON: Failed to create user. Exiting.
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory, i.e. Ambari does not know how to manage Hadoop for your Linux distro. And there is no explicit question in your post. So, what do you want to know??

Comment: hadoop is set up i fellow all the steps of installation but at last when i am creating user it give me this message i do not know what is missing

Comment: From problem description it can be seen that you are running ambari-server setup and hitting error as listed. Such error appears when you try to setup ambari on OS which is not supported by Ambari.

Answer (score 0):

The OS is not support for ambari.
You can get through this by:
1.get the os infomation:

```sh
cd /usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_commons
python2
```

```py
>>> from os_check import OSCheck
>>> OSCheck.os_distribution()
('centos', '7.9.2009', 'Core')
```

2.put the info into amabri os configuration:

```sh
vi /usr/lib/ambari-server/lib/ambari_commons/resources/os_family.json
```

For my example, get `centos`,`7` from `('centos', '7.9.2009', 'Core')`
put to os family `redhat` in `os_family.json`.
`centos` is a element for `distro` list and `7` is a element for `versions` list.

`linux mint`, you could try ubuntu or debain.

Comment: My purpose to answer it , is to record this solution to get pass this check. It finally depends whether the OS enviroment support ambari-server.